# GPU stream processors speed (Hz)

Tags: gpu, multi-processor

I've recently purchased a "Radeon HD 6870 1GB GDDR5" which spec says operates at 915 MHz and has 1120 stream processors.

My question is simple; Does all 1120 stream processors operate at 915 MHz, or is it shared, or is it something completely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the stream processors operate in parallel, and while their individual operation is independent of one another, they are all [synchronous with eachother](https://superuser.com/questions/318204/what-do-the-terms-asynchronous-and-synchronous-mean-with-respect-to-the-defi/318357#318357).  This means that they all share the same common clock, so in this case, *each* of the individual 1120 stream processors operates at 915 MHz.

While this is *similar* to having multiple cores in a CPU, it is not entirely the same thing.  Each stream processor is controlled together by the main GPU, which directs *how* the data in each stream is to be handled all-at-one (similar to the way [SIMD instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) are handled on a CPU).